# Deploy Apache Storm on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-storm

I am trying to run official [storm-deploy](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-deploy/wiki) project. Got a storm cluster running on my local machine.
How would run a Topology on storm cluster?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think using [Wirbelsturm](https://github.com/miguno/wirbelsturm) you can quickly deploy your topology to Amazon AWS